# Defining functions to shorthand

Tags: c++

Sometimes in coding contests I see stuff like

```
#define FOR(a,b,c)      for (i64(a)=(b);(a)<(i64)(c);(a)++)
```

Is this considered good/bad practice, and are there any other effects (on performance, stability -- anything?).

Basically, if it's "shorter" to type out `FOR(a,b,c)`, why not always do that?

Comment: It's only shorter when you type it. It's much longer when you have to read it. In particular, newcomers to your project have to learn all the idiosyncrasies that are encapsulated in macros instead of just being able to read the code as written.

Comment: @PeteBecker To use a crude analogy, would it be like speaking in another dialect? I'm saying the same thing you are, but using different jargon that you have to pick apart in order to understand?

Comment: Sort of, but that gives it more legitimacy than it deserves. A dialect is more widely shared. And this particular one hides a great deal of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At run-time it shouldn't perform any worse than a fully written-out version. That's because the preprocessor macro gets expanded before compilation takes place, so it has no effect on what the compiler sees.

The main argument against it would probably be readability. You have to know exactly what `FOR` is going to expand to, and be certain that it does what you expect. For a throwaway project or a prototype, that may not be an issue. In bigger or longer-term projects, you'd probably find it becoming a burden, especially when you're trying to debug the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is not more efficient. It does guarantee the same thing is being done the same way every time. Usually a function is used for this but the macro may be saving the function call and in some cases this would be more efficient.

Why not always use the macro? Because you probably do not always need the i64 cast which is why the for loop as a general construct exists.

Answer (score 0):

I personally avoid macros, unless I really can't do without them.

From *Google C++ Style Guide* 
 http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Preprocessor_Macros :

> Macros mean that the code you see is not the same as the code the compiler sees. This can introduce unexpected behavior, especially since macros have global scope.

Answer (score 0):

In coding contests people use every trick in the book to reduce things.

Is that good practice.

I think not for the simple reason - maintenance.

Also IMHO macros are a very bad idea.